# How can I identify different combinations of binary variables stored in columns in a data frame using R

Tags: r, tidyverse

I have a data frame where each row represents an individual identifier and a series of columns with flags that represent certain characteristics related to that identifier. The characteristics are not mutually exclusive and an identifier can have one or more characteristics. Let's call them `a, b, c`. I'm interested in understanding what combinations of these characteristics exist in the data i.e., in how many rows does `a, b, c, a+b, a+c, b+c, a+b+c` occur?

Using R, I could code this up in a nice little tidyverse `case_when` pipe... However, I'm looking for a solution that can scale for a higher number of characteristics. Once you add a few more columns, the number of possibilities increases exponentially and hard coding becomes impractical and prone to error.

I've pulled together some example data here...

```
set.seed(100)

example_data <- data.frame(
  id = (1:20),
  a = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20),
  b = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20),
  c = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20),
  d = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20),
  e = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20),
  f = sample(0:1, replace = TRUE, size = 20))
```

Along with a mockup of what my desired output is.

```
combination count
a           1
b           0
c           4
...
a+b         2
a+c         0
a+d         0
a+e         0
a+f         1
a+b+c       0
a+b+d       0
a+b+e       1
a+b+f       0
a+c+d       1
a+c+e       0
...
a+b+c+d+e   1
...
a+b+c+d+e+f 1
...
```

I'm at a loss for how to even approach this problem and would appreciate any tips, advice or potential solutions using R. Bonus points if you are able to use the tidyverse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try:

```
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(purrr)

# Create combination labels 
labs <- setdiff(names(example_data), "id") %>%
  map(seq_along(.), combn, x = ., paste, collapse = "+") %>%
  unlist()

# Create combinations and count
example_data %>%
  pivot_longer(-id) %>%
  filter(value == 1) %>%
  group_by(id) %>%
  summarise(cmbs = map(1:n(), combn, x = name, FUN = paste, collapse = "+"), .groups = "drop") %>%
  unnest(cmbs) %>%
  mutate(cmbs = factor(cmbs, levels = labs)) %>% # Convert to factor so absent combinations aren't lost when counting
  count(cmbs, .drop = FALSE) %>%                 # Need to use .drop = FALSE argument to prevent zero counts being dropped
  arrange(cmbs) 

# A tibble: 63 × 2
   cmbs      n
   <fct> <int>
 1 a        12
 2 b        12
 3 c         7
 4 d         9
 5 e        10
 6 f        10
 7 a+b       8
 8 a+c       3
 9 a+d       5
10 a+e       4
# … with 53 more rows
# ℹ Use `print(n = ...)` to see more rows
```

Comment: Thanks heaps @Ritchie Sacramento! This works perfectly. Nice pick up on the factorial too. I edited my question to remove it, lest it confuse others. Cheers!